# std::tuple foreach implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, template, template-meta-programming

I wrote a "foreach" implementation for `std::tuple`:

```
#pragma once

#include <tuple>
/**
 * Callback example:

struct Call{
    float k=0;

    template<typename T, int Index>        // lambda function not efficient than this. Tested -O2 clang, gcc 4.8
    inline void call(T &&t){
        std::cout << t.h << " ; " << "id = " << Index << std::endl;
    }
};
*/


namespace TUPLE_ITERATOR{
    template<typename Tuple, int index, int size>
    struct LOOP{
        template <typename Callback>
        static inline void wind(Tuple&& tuple, Callback&& callback){
            callback.template call<decltype(std::get<index>(tuple)), index> (std::get<index>(tuple));
            LOOP<Tuple, index+1, size>::wind( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<Callback>(callback) );
        }
    };

    template<typename Tuple, int size>
    struct LOOP_BACK{
        template <typename Callback>
        static inline void wind_reverse(Tuple&& tuple, Callback&& callback){
            callback.template call<decltype(std::get<size>(tuple)), size>( std::get<size>(tuple) );
            LOOP_BACK<Tuple, size-1>::wind_reverse( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<Callback>(callback) );
        }
    };

    // stop specialization
    template<typename Tuple, int size>
    struct LOOP<Tuple, size, size> {
        template <typename Callback>
        static inline void wind(Tuple&& , Callback&& ){
            // end
        }
    };
    template<typename Tuple>
    struct LOOP_BACK<Tuple, -1>{
        template <typename Callback>
        static inline void wind_reverse(Tuple&& , Callback&& ){
            // end
        }
    };
}

template<typename Tuple, typename Callback>
static void inline iterate_tuple(Tuple&& tuple, Callback&& callback){
    TUPLE_ITERATOR::LOOP< Tuple, 0, std::tuple_size< typename std::decay<Tuple>::type >::value >
            ::template wind<Callback>( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<Callback>(callback) );
}

template<typename Tuple, typename Callback>
static void inline iterate_tuple_back(Tuple&& tuple, Callback&& callback){
    TUPLE_ITERATOR::LOOP_BACK< Tuple, std::tuple_size< typename std::decay<Tuple>::type >::value-1 >
            ::template wind_reverse<Callback>( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<Callback>(callback) );
}

// Call:
// iterate_tuple(Callback(), std::make_tuple(1,2,3,"asdaa"));
```

But I look at [how other folks do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple), and I see that they do this in another way. They get an array of indices, and then recursively call the `callback` function. Is my implementation worse than that? I ask this because if I call `tuple_iterator` twice, with the same parameters, the compiler starts to use asm "calls". Look **[HERE](http://goo.gl/oIkT79)**, on the red.

```
void TUPLE_ITERATOR::LOOP<std::tuple<std::pair<int, Data>,
std::pair<int, Data> >, 0, 2>:
```

Comment: I used to use recursion a lot with templates. But I have moved from recursion to using `std::integer_sequence` and `std::tuple` to get the equivalent of a loop (though underneath in the standard code it is still recursion it is not visible from my code and thus easier to read).

Comment: So, does your implementation suffers from such "issue", like mine?

Comment: If you're able to move to C++17, you could probably replace all this with one fold-expression.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Loki's solution does not enforce the order in which the function calls are performed, because [the order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934909/1157100). Here's a C++14 solution that ensures the function is called from left to right:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ...Indices>
void for_each_impl(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{1,
        (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
    };
}

template <typename Tuple, typename F>
void for_each(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f) {
    constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
    for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
                  std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

I use `swallow{f(x)...}` to force the evaluation order. It works because the order in which the arguments to a brace initializer are evaluated is the order in which they appear. You can then use it like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for_each(std::make_tuple(1, '2', 3.3), [](auto x) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    });
}
```

#### EDIT

I modified the code so it works on both [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c23e07503cceb7d7) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08e3ecf5b9529343). Here's a more in-depth explanation of `for_each_impl`.

First, we make sure that we call `f` inside a braced initializer, so the evaluation order is from left to right:

```
using swallow = int[];
swallow{f(std::get<Indices>(tuple))...};
```

But then, what if `f` does not return an integer value? What if it returns `void` for example? So we use the comma operator to make sure the expression is an integer which can be used inside the braced initializer:

```
swallow{(f(std::get<Indices>(tuple)), int{})...};
```

The expression `(f(stuff), int{})...` is a parameter pack expansion. It expands to `(f(stuff_1), int{}), (f(stuff_2), int{}), ..., (f(stuff_n), int{})`, so each expression is really an `int`, except that some side effect has been performed before. Then, to avoid nasty overloads of the comma operator by whatever is returned by `f`, we insert a `void` between `f(...)` and `int{}`. Since `operator,(SomeType, void)` can't be overloaded, this ensures that the builtin `operator,` is used, which is what we want. This might seem overkill, but we do this in highly generic code where we must assume that `f(...)` could overload `operator,`:

```
swallow{(f(std::get<Indices>(tuple)), void(), int{})...};
                                      ^~~~ Make sure the builtin operator, is used
```

Then, what happens if `for_each_impl` is sent 0 arguments? We're gonna try to create a 0-sized array, so we must make sure the array always has at least one element in it. We use a dummy int for this:

```
swallow{1, (f(std::get<Indices>(tuple)), void(), int{})...};
        ^~~~ Now the array always has at least one element in it
```

We're almost done, but now there's an anoying compiler warning saying "You're creating a temporary array 'swallow' which is never used". To silence it, I cast the `swallow{...}` to `void`. Finally, just add perfect forwarding of the Tuple and you're done:

```
(void)swallow{1, (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...};
^^^^^^ Silence warning                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Perfect forwarding
```

Note that the way I use `std::forward` here could be unsafe in other circumstances. This is because `tuple` could be double-moved-from if the function I forwarded it to had different characteristics. Consider:

```
swallow{f(function_that_moves_from_its_arg<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...};
```

Now, `tuple` might be moved-from several times:

```
swallow{
    f(function_that_moves_from_its_arg<Index1>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), // move here
    f(function_that_moves_from_its_arg<Index2>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), // move here
    f(function_that_moves_from_its_arg<Index3>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), // move here
    ...
}
```

However, I know `std::get` is a friendly function and so there's should be no problem in doing this. There's an alternative way to do it "safely", but it involves using `std::tuple_element` and it's more complicated.

Comment: Really nice solution. To be honest I don't really understand how you call target function with `swallow`. And I can't make it work http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98be1303f2670c8b

Comment: I edited my answer so it works on both Clang and GCC, and explained it better. Look at the edit above.

Comment: 'To silence it, I cast the swallow{...} to void' - It still may be truncated by compiler, I think... As you actually not use that .... void?

Comment: I've never heard of a compiler getting rid of an expression of type `void` (with side effects) because its result is never used (which is always the case, because `void` can never be used). I'm also pretty sure the language does not allow a compiler to do so, but I don't have the time to get a quote from the standard right now.

Comment: So what exactly is this "void" here? Array declaration, function declaration? [I understand that when this array instantiated, it evaluates all elements inside it (and so call f).] I just don't really understand what happens when cast array to void...

Comment: Oh, it's just a cast of the type of the expression from `int[some number]` to `void`, which causes the compiler _not_ to emit a warning because the result of that expression is not used.

Comment: Wicked! Very nice solution to this issue, I have been trying to figure a clean solution for this problem for a very long time. :D

Comment: Is it possible to return a value?

Comment: @Short What do you mean? Return a value from the function that's called on every element, or return a value from the `for_each` itself?

Comment: Hey Louis, sorry I didn't you responded until now. I was looking for a version that collected all of the values from invoking the function on each element of the tuple into a tuple as a result.

Comment: edit: I created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199709/is-there-tuple-for-each-that-returns-a-tuple-of-all-the-functions-return-value

Comment: Really minor point: why `std::forward<F>(f)` in `for_each` but not in `for_each_impl`? Does it help prevent `f` moving from _itself_ multiple times?

Answer (score 7):

I used to use recursion a lot with templates. But I have moved from recursion to using [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to get the equivalent of a loop (from posting my template code here).

Though underneath in the standard code it is still recursion it is not visible from my code and thus easier to read.

I am not trying to implement exactly what you have.
But if you look at the code you can see what I am trying to achiece and may be able to apply this technique to your code (thus making it easier to read and thus maintain).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>



// The object that defines the iteration.
// Notice the use of make_integer_sequence here (it returns integer_sequence type)
//
// This defines how we are going to iterate over the tuple T.
//    
template<typename C, typename T, typename Seq = std::make_integer_sequence<int, std::tuple_size<T>::value>>
struct TupleIterate;


// A partial specialization of the above.
// Here we convert the integer_sequence into a sequence of integers S
// We can use variable argument expansion to generate the code inline
// with this sequence.
//
template<typename C, typename T, int... S>
struct TupleIterate<C, T, std::integer_sequence<int, S...>>
{
    TupleIterate(C caller, T const& val)
    {
        // Make a tuple.
        // This takes a variable number of arguments and creates the appropriate
        // tuple. As we don't use the tuple we don't even bother to store it.
        //
        // Use Var-Arg expansion to call caller for each argument in T
        // The results of these called are passed to make_tuple()
        //
        std::make_tuple(caller(std::get<S>(val))...);
    }
};

//
// Function: To allow argument deduction
//           Pass the values as parameters and it creates the TupleIterator
//           defined above. Because it deduces the types of its arguments
//           we don't need to specify them.
template<typename C, typename T>
TupleIterate<C,T> tuple_iterate(C caller, T const& val)
{
    return TupleIterate<C,T>(caller, val);
}


// An example caller object.
// Just to show it printing.
struct Caller
{
    // It needs an operator() for each type in the tuple.
    // For ease of use I have templatized this.
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T const& data)
    {
        std::cout << "Data: " << data << "\n";
        return data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto    val = std::make_tuple(1,2,"Hi there");

    tuple_iterate(Caller(), val);
}
```

Comment: It does not compile http://goo.gl/wGaNJ8

Comment: @tower120 `std::integer_sequence` is a C++14 feature, you will need to give the option `-std=c++1y` to your compiler. Also, only the most recent compiler (often trunk versions) implement it. Choose GCC 4.9.

Comment: On the other hand, you can find several standard-compliant implementations on the internet that you can copy-paste meanwhile :)

Comment: g++ -std=c++1y call.cpp

Comment: @LokiAstari Look here http://goo.gl/Eixw1v. At the bottom of assembly output 'TupleIterate<Caller, std::tuple<int, int, char const*>, '  Instead of proceed to put std::cout call's, compiler replace them with 2 TupleIterate calls. I mean, now its not plain list of std::cout calls (like it was with single tuple_iterate call). This is that issue, which have my own implementation.

Comment: So the compiler decided not to inline the code. I don't see the problem. Its the compilers job to decide when and if the code should be inlined. If the compiler decides its more effecient not to inline then I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're exclusively interested in `for_each`, the Morwenn/Martin York response is pretty neat. Otherwise, a meaningful generalisation is the use of `std::tuple` with STL algorithms. To that end, your good bet is Jonathan Müller's [`tuple_iterator`](https://foonathan.net/blog/2017/03/01/tuple-iterator.html). That would give you iterator access to `std::tuple`, which you would also be able to use for `std::for_each`, in particular.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tuple_iterator` is not as generalised as I initially thought. One cannot pass a couple of them to `std::for_each` with a member function to be called on each element in the tuple. I couldn't figure out a way to deduce the element's type from the iterator to guide the member function.

Comment: I need to correct myself on the last comment: My failure was due to my (old-school) trial for using `std::mem_fun`. I managed to make the member function call I was after using generic lambdas:

```auto t = my_tuple();
std::for_each(begin(t), end(t), [](auto& e){e.mf();});
```

where `mf` is the name of the member function I'd like to call. In my case, my `mf` has important side-effects and I pass by non-`const` reference. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of [Louisse Dionne's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11245/louis-dionne) solution and simplifying `for_each` slightly by using `index_sequence_for` we could arrive at this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ...Indices>
void for_each_impl(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{1,
        (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
    };
}

template<typename F, typename... Args>
void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple, F&& f)
{
    for_each_impl(tuple, std::forward<F>(f), std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```