# for_each for tuple-likes

Tags: c++, template, c++14, iteration

I've implemented a C++14 `for_each` for tuple-like objects. It's similar to `std::for_each` in that it also returns the functor once it's done. Usage examples:

With a visitor functor:

```
// visitor functor
struct print {
    void operator()(int x) const { std::cout << "int: " << x << '\n'; }
    void operator()(double x) const { std::cout << "double: " << x << '\n'; }
};

auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.14);
for_each(t, print());  // prints: int: 1
                       //         int: 2
                       //         double: 3.14
```

With a C++14 generic lambda:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.14);
for_each(t, [](auto x) { std::cout << x << '\n'; });  // prints: 1
                                                      //         2
                                                      //         3.14
```

With a stateful functor:

```
struct summer {
    void operator()(int x) noexcept { sum += x; }

    int sum = 0;
};

auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int sum = for_each(t, summer()).sum;  // sum == 15
```

With a `std::array`:

```
std::array<char, 5> arr = {{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}};
for_each(arr, [](char c) { std::cout << c; });  // prints: hello
std::cout << '\n';
```

Implementation:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {

// workaround for default non-type template arguments
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

// process the `From::value`-th element
template<typename FromIndex,
         typename ToIndex,
         typename Tuple,
         typename UnaryFunction>
struct for_each_t {
    constexpr UnaryFunction&& operator()(Tuple&& t, UnaryFunction&& f) const
    {
        std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f)(
                std::get<FromIndex::value>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
        return for_each_t<index_t<FromIndex::value + 1>,
                          ToIndex,
                          Tuple,
                          UnaryFunction>()(
                std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f));
    }
};

// specialization for empty tuple-likes 
template<typename FromIndex, typename Tuple, typename UnaryFunction>
struct for_each_t<FromIndex, index_t<0>, Tuple, UnaryFunction> {
    constexpr UnaryFunction&& operator()(Tuple&&, UnaryFunction&& f) const
    {
        return std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f);
    }
};

// specialization for last element
template<typename ToIndex, typename Tuple, typename UnaryFunction>
struct for_each_t<index_t<ToIndex::value - 1>, ToIndex, Tuple, UnaryFunction> {
    constexpr UnaryFunction&& operator()(Tuple&& t, UnaryFunction&& f) const
    {
        std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f)(
                std::get<ToIndex::value - 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
        return std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f);
    }
};

}  // namespace detail

template<typename Tuple, typename UnaryFunction>
constexpr UnaryFunction for_each(Tuple&& t, UnaryFunction&& f)
{
    return detail::for_each_t<detail::index_t<0>,
                              detail::index_t<std::tuple_size<
                                  std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>
                              >::value>,
                              Tuple,
                              UnaryFunction>()(
            std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f));
}
```

Specific concerns I have:

1. <del>I'm passing in & out functors by universal reference rather than by value (as `std::for_each` does). I'm concerned whether this can cause problems.</del> Following the advice from answerers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365019/return-by-universal-reference?noredirect=1#comment64142860_38365019), I've changed the return type of `for_each` to `UnaryFunction` (but note the return types of `for_each_t` can remain unchanged).
2. Whether the design can be simplified.
3. I've seen people do it with `std::index_sequence`. The accepted answer in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51407/stdtuple-foreach-implementation?rq=1) is the shortest version I've seen, but it feels a bit like a hack. Also, it generates [longer assembly code](https://godbolt.org/g/UmCXSY) than [my version](https://godbolt.org/g/u4C8Gp) does. (My version generates the exact same assembly code as a [completely manually expanded version](https://godbolt.org/g/83O5BM).)

Comment: Your code use template recursion which is how people originally approached this type of problem. The issue here is that compilers only have to implement so many levels of template recursion to be compliant so with bigger tuples this may start to fail on some compilers. The more modern technique is to use an iterative approach (using `std::index_sequence`). I don't have time this evening to look hard but if nobody has answered by tomorrow I'll dig in.

Comment: @LokiAstari No one has answered yet.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to start with your concern #3:

> I've seen people do it with `std::index_sequence`. The accepted answer
>   in [this
>   post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51407/stdtuple-foreach-implementation?rq=1)
>   is the shortest version I've seen, but it feels a bit like a hack.
>   Also, it generates [longer assembly
>   code](https://godbolt.org/g/UmCXSY) than [my
>   version](https://godbolt.org/g/u4C8Gp) does. (My version generates the
>   exact same assembly code as a [completely manually expanded
>   version](https://godbolt.org/g/83O5BM).)

The placement of a single `constexpr` in the [index-sequence version](https://godbolt.org/g/6mIHmT) makes the generated assembly identical for [both versions](https://godbolt.org/g/ZGZHND). The missing `constexpr` was on the `for_each_impl` that was doing most of the work in the index-sequence version

---

Concern #2:

> Whether the design can be simplified.

At this point, there isn't more that I can say other than [Louis Dionne's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67394/49895) is much simpler than your solution:

> ```
> #include <cstddef>
> #include <tuple>
> #include <utility>
>
> template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ...Indices>
> void for_each_impl(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
>     using swallow = int[];
>     (void)swallow{1,
>         (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
>     };
> }
>
> template <typename Tuple, typename F>
> void for_each(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f) {
>     constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
>     for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
>                   std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
> }
> ```

Fixed by adding the two missing `constexpr`s (one each function):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ...Indices>
constexpr void for_each_impl(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{1,
        (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
    };
}

template <typename Tuple, typename F>
constexpr void for_each(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f) {
    constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
    for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
                  std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Compared to your code, this is much easier to understand, largely because there is much less code, as well as the fact that this style of doing something for each element of a parameter pack is pretty standard nowadays.

I know you are concerned that this feels like a hack, but I assure you, it is not really. It's the easiest way to regain a parameter pack from a tuple-like type.

Additionally, doing work with parameter packs tends to be more efficient than recursive functions (in terms of compile-time). That is not something to disregard casually.

Furthermore, compilers have a pretty small limit for `constexpr` recursion compared to runtime recursion. On my version of gcc, it was 500. Yes, that's not a trivially small amount and it would work for most tuples you pass to your `for_each`, but different compilers could choose different allowed recursion depths. Also, it's not inconceivable that I would want to have a `std::array<int, 1024>`, which would simply break with your version (you would probably want `std::for_each` in this case, though).

Comment: Thanks! I assume the fold expression in C++17 would make things a lot easier?

Comment: @ZizhengTai I would say that for "foreach", fold expressions don't really make it easier (maybe you can fold over the comma operator, but that doesn't seem any easier than this) - fold expressions seem more targeted at "reduce".